# Draw d3 svg circles on openlayers 3 maps

Tags: openlayers, d3

I am new to openlayers and d3. I tried following example
http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/d3.html

I see we need to add d3 features on a canvas and project it on an openlayers Vector layer. Issue is that I only have a csv of latitude and longitude so I really can't figure out how to create features out of that.

I tried something like the below, but could not make it render as a feature.

```
var svg = d3.select("#emap").insert("svg:svg")
             .attr("width", width).attr("height", height);
```

I am using D3 because data points are huge(about a million) and I need to show different density points at different zoom levels.

Comment: Pleas show what you have tried, ideally in somethign like jsFiddle or [codepen, as used by OL3, themselves](https://codepen.io/pen?&editors=1010)